# Dropdownmenu in Android(2.3.3)

Tags: android, menu

I would like to build a dropdownmenu for Android 2.3.3 . But I dont know how to do that. Can somebody recommend some examples(Github etc.)? It would be very helpfull. There is a sample pictures of a Dropdownmenu below.

Thanks

[image: Dropboxmenu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's part of the action bar in android 3.0 and up.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

To use it in earlier version you have to create it your self or I think you can use open source action bar. like http://actionbarsherlock.com/

You could just build a list inside a relative layout and make it invisible until you press the button.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a normal [Spinner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html) to me.

Here is an example: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html

Comment: It is clear in the title that he wants to do it in `Android v2.3.3` while your answer only applies to `Android v3.0+`

Comment: @mr5 The Spinner widget has been around since API lvl 1. There is nothing about it that requires v3.0+...