# Drop down menu in android2.3

Tags: android, drop-down-menu

how to create a drop down menu in android?I tried spinner,but its dialog box is covering in the entire screen when it is in landscape mode.also width of dialog cannot be adjusted.I need drop down menu working for andorid2.3.can any one help me i am a fresher in this field?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dropdownmenu in Android(2.3.3)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10063564/851432)

Comment: You can use pop-up menu with ActionBarSherlock accordnig to this 
[answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8325582/android-pop-up-menu-with-icons-similar-to-google-map-app-new-version-6/11765787#11765787

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) and use IcsSpinner instead of regular spinner for dropdown effect. It works API 8 onwards.